# How do I convert from one Java type to another Java type using Spring Camel?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have the following Camel route in a Spring application:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() {       

        from("{{route.from}}")
        .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(ExternalPrice.class))
        .split(body())
        .convertBodyTo(InternalPriceDto.class)
        .end()
        .to("{{route.mail}}");
    }
}
```

I have a Spring component that is annotated as a Camel converter:

```
@Component
@Converter
public class ExternalPriceToInternalPrice {

    @Converter
    public static InternalPriceDto toReturn(ExternalPrice price) {
        // some logic but for brevity in stackoverflow...
        return new InternalPriceDto(price.getValue(), price.getProduct());
    }
}
```

I'm using Gradle. I'm new to Camel but have read this [doc](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/3.20.x/spring-boot.html#typeconverter) and this [doc](https://camel.apache.org/manual/type-converter.html). But it's not clear to me how I need to register this converter using Spring & Gradle. Should I just use a Camel processor instead?

Comment: This would appear to be a very common need. Yet, @Converter seems overly complex. Looks like you have to use Maven plug-in and create a jar file with just the converter class. Creating a bean that does this conversion and using .bean(beanInstance) is much simpler. I suppose with 20 views and no responses that means that `@Converter` is a bad option (esoteric, complex, and ill-advised).

Answer (score 0):

Registering new converters to Apache camel is like you said, either overly complex or that the documentation how to do so is simply lacking.

I would however recommend just creating simple converter class with no extra dependencies to camel and maybe not even for spring then using processor or a simple method to "abstract" away the use of converter from the route.

This way the converter can potentially be used even in projects that do not use spring or camel framework with little to no modifications.

```java
import com.example.beans.ExampleA;
import com.example.beans.ExampleAToExampleBConverter;
import com.example.beans.ExampleB;

@Component
public class MySpringBootRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    ExampleAToExampleBConverter converter;

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySpringBootRouter.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        Predicate bodyIsOfTypeExampleB = body().isInstanceOf(ExampleB.class);

        from("direct:hello")
            .routeId("hello")
            .process(this::convertBodyToExampleB)
            .filter(bodyIsOfTypeExampleB)
                .log("Body converted succesfully to type " + ExampleB.class.getName() )
            .end()
        ;
    }

    private Object convertBodyToExampleB(Exchange exchange) {
        
        try {
            ExampleA exampleA = exchange.getMessage().getBody(ExampleA.class);
            return converter.convertToExampleB(exampleA);
        } catch (TypeConversionException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to convert body.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```